# Unable to install watchify package

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify, watchify

I am trying to install watchify package via npm but I am failing. After a little while the command just stops its execution. Any idea on how to fix this issue? Thx

```
npm install --save watchify@2.4.0
npm WARN package.json thumbnail-gulp@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json thumbnail-gulp@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json thumbnail-gulp@1.0.0 No README data

> fsevents@0.3.8 install /Users/sandropalmieri/Documents/mycode/reactjs/thumbnail-gulp/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild
```

Comment: add `-d` flag to get more details when you install packages. Ex: `npm install --save watchify@2.4.0 -d`

Comment: ok I did and here is where I get sucked:                                                     **bold**gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.1
gyp info using node@0.12.7 | darwin | x64
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz'code'